# iOS Notifications - is it possible to store them locally?

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is there any way to push notifications without using a web server? I would like to schedule and store the notifications locally, maybe using Core Data. I haven't used the push API before.

I also plan on adding interactive features with iOS 8.

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Local Notification

[Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks so much! Has Apple provided any documentation for the new interactive elements in ios 8? If so can you link it or give me a search term? I can't find them on the dev center.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html